# Stack allocated objects defined in member initializer list

Tags: c++, qt

Take a look at this class derived by Qt's QGroupBox:

```
class Profile : public QGroupBox {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Profile(const QString& name);

private:
    QString name;
    QHBoxLayout layout;
}
```

Okay, so I'm writing a custom widget with Qt, and I have a QHBoxLayout as a member, thing is, I'm not going to need it after the Profile gets deleted, so I obviously created it on the stack, now, what's the correct way to instantiate it?

```
Profile(const QString& name)
    : name(name)
    , layout(QHBoxLayout(this->name, this))
{ /* STUFF */ }
```

But it also compiles this way:

```
Profile(const QString& name)
    : name(name)
    , layout(this->name, this)
{ /* STUFF */ }
```

Comment: The 1st way creates a temporary `QHBoxLayout` and then passes it to `layout`'s copy constructor. The 2nd way initializes `layout` directly. The 2nd way is preferred.

Comment: Does the first example actually compile?  `QObject` and types derived from it are non-copyable -- [no copy ctor or assignment operator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator).